# Interpolate inside a yaml list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, yaml

I know I can do:

```
en:
  greeting:
    hello, %{name}!
```

t('greeting', {:name => "homie"})
=> "hello, homie!"

but how can I do:

```
en:
  greetings:
    - Hey, %{name}
    - Wassup, %{name}
```

?  It appears that interpolation is not performed on lists...  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You have to explicitly tell yaml what is multiline. That's the role of |

```
en:
  greetings: |
    - Hey, %{name}
    - Wassup, %{name}
```

Comment: t(:greetings, {:name => "homie"}) returns "- Hey, homie\n- Wassup, homie"...  It's not giving back an array as I need it to...